# Issue with lua51 c-shared library

Tags: c, gcc, lua, shared-libraries, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to compile a simple example program that depends on a shared library (so) that depends on liblua51.so. My source file is example.c and here is the command I am using to compile it (it is written in C)

```
cc -Wall -fPIC -ldl -o a.out -I./ste-linux/ste-interface-files/c/ -L./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries/ example.c -lm -llua51 -lste -lm -ldl
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `sinh'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `ceil'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `atan2'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `tanh'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `cosh'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `fmod'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `acos'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `sin'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `atan'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `asin'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `exp'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `tan'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `cos'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `log'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `pow'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `log10'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `sqrt'
./ste-linux/ste-shared-libraries//liblua51.so: undefined reference to `floor'
```

I have read a bunch of other threads on stackoverflow saying adding the -lm flag will fix this, but no matter where I put the -L and -lm -ldl in the command, these undefined references will not go away.

I am trying to compile this lib on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Help please

Comment: Something is probably wrong with the way you built `liblua`. Can you try using the version that is provided by Ubuntu instead, and see if you still have problems?

Comment: i dont think i can do that, because it the shared lib i need was built against this specific version is there a tool i can use to debug this type of problem?

Comment: You can write a simple program that only uses Lua. Compile it against your version, then compile it against the system version, and see if there are differences in behavior. Worry about your shared-lib later, debug one problem at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the shared library I was using was built with a different version of GCC. After I downgrade from Ubuntu 11.04 (from 12.04 LTS) it was resolved.